# SQL Joining 3 tables tag system codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join, tags

I've been trying to come up with a tag system for my posts and I am having troubles getting the values I want. Rather, I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic of the joining of tables. I've tried to find information to help me along but I guess I need someone to really lay down the basics.

Anyway, these are my tables (shortening the posts table);

```
POSTS
post_id
post_title
post_freetext

POST_TAGS
post_id
tag_id

TAGS
tag_id
tag_text
```

What I am trying to do is fetching all posts connected to a single tag.

My CodeIgniter code looks like this;

```
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('posts');
   $this->db->join('post_tags', 'post_tags.post_id = posts.post_id' ,'inner');
   $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.tag_id = posts.post_id', 'inner');
   $this->db->where('tag_text =', $tagid);
   $this->db->order_by('posts.post_id', 'desc');
   $q = $this->db->get();
```

$tagid in this case is the string (read tag) that I am looking for.

I was successful in joining two tables and fetching the posts but then I realized I would not be able to allow the user to look at all the tags (and thus I needed a separate "tag" table). Can't seem to get this right though.

Any help at all would be very much appreciated and I do realize that this question has probably been answered multiple times - still, can't wrap my head around the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About logic of joining this page could help

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

in you code you have a mistake in second join

> $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.tag_id = posts.post_id', 'inner');

Those two tables are not connected(where is foreign key and where it points).

You have to use table post_tags not posts
so use something like this:
'post_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id'

Comment: This is a perfect logical map, I was looking for something like this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('posts');
   $this->db->join('post_tags', 'post_tags.post_id = posts.post_id' ,'inner');
   $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.tag_id = post_tags.tag_id', 'inner');
   $this->db->where('tag_text', $tagid);
   $this->db->order_by('posts.post_id', 'desc');
   $q = $this->db->get();
```